# Field dependent property

Tags: c#, properties, visual-studio-2015, null

I'm writing a wrapper class for a device SDK to make it easier for a big project to handle it (e.g. not typos on strings in `getParameter(string parameter)` and simplifying the method calling for our purpose). The device has some properties that I can get and set, but **only if the device is connected** (so the property is dependent on the field `device` not being null and connected) and I can't wrap my head around how to handle it. I read that throwing exceptions in getters might be a bad idea. I could make the property nullable, but I suspect that the problem is rather in the design.

```
class MyClass
{
    private Device device; //SDK device

    public string Name
    {
        get //set is pretty much the same
        {
            if (!device.IsConnected)
                //return null and have nullable property? throw NotConnectedException?
            return device.getParameter("Name");
        }
    }
}
```

I could transform the properties into methods, and throw exceptions, but my mentor preferred them as properties. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Not sure what you really want, but you could start with having all the device dependent handling in one class, and having exception handling around this, afterwards you could make your getters and setters device independent - who knows maybe you need to change device on the fly in the future

Comment: String is by default nullable. If you are only operating with strings, dont hasitate to return null.

Comment: I'm afraid there are some more properties that are ints, doubles and enums as well, but nice suggestion for the string ones, thanks.
@serup Do you mean like wrapping the Device as well, and have my wrapper have an instance of the devicewrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would extract the logics of connection to another class, so that you can easily change this in future, and so that you do not repeat yourself writing many `if (!device.IsConnected)...` checks.
For example, what if you can now only work with devices which are connected and have `ErrorStatus` = 0. Will you change every condition in every property?

I would write something like:

```
class DeviceWrapperFactory
{
    public static DeviceWrapper Connect(Device device)
    {
        if (!_device.IsConnected)
        {
            // assume trying to reconnect here if possible
            // like "if (!device.TryToConnect())"
            throw new DeviceConnectionFailedException();
        }

        return new DeviceWrapper(_device);
    }
}

class DeviceWrapper
{
    private Device device;

    DeviceWrapper(Device device)
    {
        _device = device;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return device.getParameter("Name");
        }
    }
}
```

That way, you will be able to do:

```
try
{
    Console.WriteLine(DeviceWrapperFactory.Connect(usbDevice).Name);
    // or
    var usbDeviceWrapper = DeviceWrapperFactory.Connect(usbDevice);
    Console.WriteLine(usbDeviceWrapper.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(usbDeviceWrapper.AnotherProperty);
}
catch (DeviceConnectionFailedException dcfe)
{
    // ...
}
```

You may also want to create Devices object pool instead of factory, or whatever else you want. This example just shows the idea.

It does also depend on your architecture and your `Device` class default behavior. If it is **always connected**, except for exceptional technical problems cases, then you should use exceptions. If your devices can either be connected or not, with equal chance, then you need to use booleans or nulls.

In general, it is almost never possible to say which architecture or approach is better. We would need to learn the whole system to make such decisions. You need to try.

Comment: Brilliant explanation and example. I'll try to implement it in a way similar to this. Thanks!